# How to add a header to a Groovy SwingBuilder table?

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder

How do I add a header to the table defined below?

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

data = [[first:'qwer', last:'asdf'],
        [first:'zxcv', last:'tyui'],
        [first:'ghjk', last:'bnm']]

swing = new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title:'table test'){
    table {
        tableModel( list : data ) {
            propertyColumn(header:'First Name', propertyName:'first')
            propertyColumn(header:'last Name', propertyName:'last')
        }
    }
}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the table in a scrollPane, the headers appear:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

data = [[first:'qwer', last:'asdf'],
        [first:'zxcv', last:'tyui'],
        [first:'ghjk', last:'bnm']]

swing = new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title:'table test'){
  scrollPane {
    table {
        tableModel( list : data ) {
            propertyColumn(header:'First Name', propertyName:'first')
            propertyColumn(header:'last Name', propertyName:'last')
        }
    }
  }
}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```

See item one [on this page](http://www.chka.de/swing/table/faq.html) for an explanation why

Comment: Thanks! Also, based on your reference, I posted an example without using the scrollPane

Answer (score 1):

Table header is a separate widget that must be added explicitly.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.BorderLayout

data = [[first:'qwer', last:'asdf'],
        [first:'zxcv', last:'tyui'],
        [first:'ghjk', last:'bnm']]

swing = new SwingBuilder()
frame = swing.frame(title:'table test'){
    def tab = table(constraints:BorderLayout.CENTER) {
        tableModel( list : data ) {
            propertyColumn(header:'First Name', propertyName:'first')
            propertyColumn(header:'Last Name', propertyName:'last')
        }
    }
    widget(constraints:BorderLayout.NORTH, tab.tableHeader)
}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```